# execFile function with node and ffmpeg shaves off 1 second of video created

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am using the latest node js and windows 10. I am creating a 5 seconds video from a single image using ffmpeg in the node js child process. Following is the code:

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

// Command to transform
//ffmpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.jpg -i 3D_Transition_02.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]format=rgba,scale=1280:720,split[img][a]; [1]format=rgb24,negate,scale=1280:720[tr];[a][tr]overlay=format=gbrp[al];[img][al]alphamerge,setsar=1,format=yuva444p" -an -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 0 -quality realtime -auto-alt-ref 0 a1vp8.mkv

let str = "[0]format=rgba,scale=1280:720,split[img][a]; [1]format=rgb24,negate,scale=1280:720[tr];[a][tr]overlay=format=gbrp[al];[img][al]alphamerge,setsar=1,format=yuva444p";

const child = execFile('ffmpeg', ['-framerate', '30', '-loop', '1', '-t', '5', '-i', '1.jpg', '-i', '3D_Transition_02.mp4', '-filter_complex', str, '-an', '-c:v', 'libvpx', '-crf', '10', '-b:v', '0', '-quality', 'realtime', '-auto-alt-ref', '0', 'a2vp8.mkv'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error:', stderr);
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('Success', stdout);
});

console.log('Video created');
```

The video is created successfully but...as you can see in the command it should be 5 seconds long. The first time i created the video it was 5 seconds long, but on the second and later attempts it's 4 seconds long(in the gom player it shows a blank area in the play seek bar)!!!

**When I right click and view details of the file it is 5 seconds long.**

the behavior is the I first get the console message: video created, and then after a few seconds (when the file is rendered) I get the std out "Success" message.

Any ideas why it's behaving like this? I also tried the execFileSync and it also created a 4 second video (at least as per the gom player play seek bar).

Comment: Test with multiple players. ffmpeg's output will be deterministic for same command with same inputs.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I tested it with multiple players. I noticed that the videos I have created have an alpha channel in it as I used your previous commands to create them with transition. The missing portion on the seek bar is exactly 1.25 seconds which is the length of the transition.